# Avoiding fat controllers in Javascript MVC

Tags: javascript, express, kraken.js

Imagine the following, you need to fetch some data from a database and then make a request to an external API and merge the db and API data together, do some calculation and return the result to the frontend.

That's a lot of code and i don't like fat controllers so I just put it into a "processing" library into the "lib" folder. Structure as below:

```
controller/
   controller.js
lib/
   processing.js
models/
```

Now the fat code moved from the controller to the "processing" lib. I don't like this either.

What would be a good solution to this problem? How can I provide some better structure?

Info: I am developing a Kraken.js/Express.js based app

Comment: asp.net mvc tag ????

Comment: It seems like you are going to have a lot of code somewhere no matter what, which is fine if you aren't duplicating code.

Comment: @Shyju mistake, thanks for noticing